# Is it possible to get whether the Foreign key allow nulls using sys.foreign_keys

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have written the following script to list out the foreign keys

```
SELECT
object_name(parent_object_id),
object_name(referenced_object_id),
name
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE parent_object_id = object_id('tableName')
```

I would like to get whether this foriegn key allow nulls or not in the corresponding table, also the name is displaying as `FK_TableName_PK_TableName_FKColumn` instead of that I need to display the `FK` name directly can some one help me

Comment: nullability is a property of the column(s) involved. It's not a property of the foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
SP_HELP 'tablename'
```

it gives all the information about the table including columns (if they are nullable or not), FK, References (See last table), etc.

Or if you only need constraints info use this

```
EXEC sys.sp_helpconstraint 'tablename','nomsg'
```